# My custom Eclipse IMarkers are not being showed after I reopen the file

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Currently I have my own custom IMarker:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers"
    id="com.test.package.custommarker"
    name="Custom Markers">
    <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker" />
    <persistent value="true" />
</extension>
```

And the IMarkers are created by this code:

```
IMarker marker = this.resource.createMarker("com.test.package.custommarker");
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, description);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LOCATION, "line: " + line + ", col: " + col);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line);     
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, col);
```

At the 1st execution the Editor is open and the IMarkers are displayed in the Editor and in the Problem view, the issue is if I reopen the file the IMarkers are only showed in the Problem view but not in the editor.
When I said the IMarkers are displayed in the Editor I mean to this:
[Editor with error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGVKS.png)

Here is how the Editor looks when I reopen the file:
[Editor after the reopen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L23SI.png).

My question is, why is this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set *both* CHAR_START and CHAR_END, or *only* LINE_NUMBER, in order for the corresponding text Annotation to be created. Also, CHAR_START and CHAR_END are document-relative, not line-relative. Step through `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractMarkerAnnotationModel#createPositionFromMarker(IMarker)` if you want to see how that works.

Comment: Thanks, you are right if I only put the line number the IMarkers are showed when I reopen the Editor

Comment: If you have more specific location information, I encourage you to use CHAR_START and CHAR_END instead.